# Cannot convert undefined or null to object in vue using firestore

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

I want to fetch product from cloud firestore which i store this way
[image: firestore]

1. HelloWorld.vue Component :

   ```
    import db from "./firebaseInit";
    export default {
      name: "HelloWorld",
      data() {
        return {
          products: [],
          imageURL: "",
        };
      },

      created () {
        db.collection("product").doc('t9tWJq7BTvqmPvxPjcxy').get();
      },
    }
   ```
2. firebaseInit.js file:

   import fireabse from 'firebase'

   import  "firebase/firestore";

   import { firebaseConfig } from "./firebaseConfig";

   const firebaseApp = fireabse.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

   export default firebaseApp.firestore();

the error i got is :

> index.esm.js?ffa6:130 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
> at hasOwnProperty ()
> at eval (prebuilt-89214b55-2a7b2673.js?c244:14410)
> at e.t (prebuilt-89214b55-2a7b2673.js?c244:14412)
> at new e (prebuilt-89214b55-2a7b2673.js?c244:16077)
> at eval (index.js?c68e:69)
> at Component.eval [as instanceFactory] (index.js?c68e:66)
> at Provider.getOrInitializeService (index.esm.js?ffa6:218)
> at Provider.getImmediate (index.esm.js?ffa6:116)
> at FirebaseAppImpl._getService (index.esm.js?cc84:220)
> at FirebaseAppImpl.firebaseAppImpl. [as firestore] (index.esm.js?cc84:432)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

#### firebaseConfig.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/storage';   // Just as an example of how to add another Firebase service. 


const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    //...
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firebase.firestore();
const storage = firebase.storage();

export { db, storage };
```

#### HelloWorld.vue (in a views folder)

```
<script>
 const fb = require("../firebaseConfig.js");
 export default {
   name: "HelloWorld",
   data() {
     return {
       productData: null
     };
   },

   created () {
     fb.db.collection("product").doc('t9tWJq7BTvqmPvxPjcxy').get()
      .then(doc => {
        if (doc.exists) {
            this.productData = doc.data();
        } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
   },
 }
</script>
```

---

Note that with this code you are [fetching only one document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document).

If you want to populate an array of products, you should [query the entire collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection), as follows:

```
  created () {
    fb.db.collection("product").get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        let productsArray = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
           let p = doc.data();
           p.id = doc.id;
           productsArray.push(p);
          }
        });
        this.products = productsArray;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
   },
```

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion is to change the way `firebase` is initiated.

1. Initialize firebase in `main.js` instead of component

   ```js
   // suggested to put this logic in main.js

   import fireabse from 'firebase'

   import "firebase/firestore";

   import { firebaseConfig } from "./firebaseConfig";

   fireabse.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)  // firebase typo in this line
   ```
2. When calling firestore methods, can directly use the `firebase` object from `import firebase from 'firebase/app';`

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

export default {
   name: "HelloWorld",
   data() {
     return {
       products: [],
       imageURL: "",
     };
   },

   async created () {
     const ref = firebase.firestore().collection("product").doc('t9tWJq7BTvqmPvxPjcxy')
     const snapshot = await ref.get(); // note the `await` keyword here
     console.log(snapshot);
     // ...using the fetched data
   },
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Please note the `async/await` keywords as the firestore `get()` is an async function call.

The key point is that, whenever some variables may be null or undefined at a moment, you can use `console.log` to print that out and check.